# Vuforia/Android Studio - Working with VideoPlayback and image targets samples at the same time

Tags: android-studio, vuforia

I need to use Vuforia, to implement AR in an android app using Android Studio.

I was able to run the samples separately with no issues. My doubt is if any one knows how to use the video playback and image target samples at the same time when the camera is active?

For example, I have two images in my database located on assets. When the first image is recognized, I need to play a video (video playback) and when the second image is recognized, another image is placed with AR above the target (image target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but perhaps it could be of an assistance nevertheless. I cannot give you any code, but I can tell you for sure that there is no real problem of doing this - in fact, it is only a matter of a correct integration between two of Vuforia's samples. Once you have implemented the functions for drawing an image on a target and for drawing a video on a target, you simply invoke the relevant function based on the target id. Looking at a specific difficulty and trying to help on that would be a lot easier, once you actually did the integration.